# Hangman: Can't display a different message when inputting an incorrect guess compared to an invalid guess?

Tags: python

I'm trying to get my hangman game to display a different message when the player inputs an incorrect guess, as compared to when they guess something invalid, like "fergwergwer" for example. I'd like it to display that it understands that was an invalid entry and not just a wrong guess.

I've been messing around with if else statements and try except statements and none of them are giving the results I want. I considered using an except: ValueError statement, but I'm not sure if its because its because of the order that I'm putting it in but its still not fixing it.

```
   for char in word:
        if char in guesses:
            print('You guessed: ', char, end = '')
        else:
            try:
                alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k',l
    ,'m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']  
                if char not in alphabet:
                    print('Thats not a letter')
                    failed += 1
            except:
                print('_ ', end = '')
                failed += 1
        if failed == 0:
            print(': You figured it out!')
            break
    guess = input('Please guess a letter!')
    guesses += guess
    if guess not in word:
        turns -= 1
        print('Wrong! You have', + turns, 'more guesses.')
        if turns == 0:
            print('Game over!')
```

I would like it to display "Wrong!" if the player guesses wrong, and "Thats not a letter!" if their input was not in the alphabet list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using this for user input:

```
word = 'guess'
alpha = input('Alphabet: ')[0]
if not alpha.isalpha():
    print('Please enter an alphabet!')
    # use value: 1
elif alpha.isalpha() and alpha.lower() not in word.lower():
    # use value: A
    print('Wrong guess')
else:
    # use value: g
    print('Correct Guess')
```

check if this works for you

Comment: You could omit the `alpha.isalpha()` part of the `elif` statement, that statement is only reached if the check for "not alpha" fails.